# Modify Chrome local extension source

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I've installed a extension from the Chrome Webstore.
Now I found the local folder of that particular extension, which is located somewhere in:

> C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Profile
>   2\Extensions\ppdakpfeaodfoasxilfdedpcodkdkbal\1.11.8

I tried modifying some js files there to change the duration of a popup which is constantely being displayed, but somehow there's no change in behaviour. I'm starting to wonder, whether a local change to the .js-file will be considered by Chrome at all, or whether Chrome has some cached version of that extension stored. If so, than why it unzips the extension at all?

I also tried to copy the whole folder to my desktop, delete the extension, and install the unpacked extension from the folder on the desktop - but that doesn't work since the extension seems to somehow recognize whether it was locally installed or not. At least it says Im not online, dunno why. The code is too complex to understand that reason.

So what options are there, if I obviously cannot modify the code in the webstore (the developer doesnt reply to any of my mails) but local unpacked installation doesnt work, and changing the unpacked files in the Chrome AppData folder isnt recognized?

Thanks

Comment: Well, you'll have to find out why it doesn't connect in unpacked installation. It might be an explicit check for the installation type which you can remove.

Comment: Yes that would be one possibility. Do you know why Chrome unpacks the Extension while installing from the Chrome-Store when it does not actually USE those files? (obviously doesnt, because modifying them doesnt change anything)

Comment: Chrome always uses the unpacked files. That popup you mention - what is it? A screenshot and the code that invokes it would be helpful.

Comment: Ok Ill recheck and let you know. Do you know when chrome says an extension is corrupted? Is there any hash/checksum calculated? I have a function which returns a boolean value and I entered "return false;" just at the start of the function and now it says -> extension corrupted. What could you wrong there? Do you know any such mechanism?

Comment: Chrome protects extensions installed from webstore against local modifications and AFAIK you can't disable that.